# Addition of ndk filters cuased apk install to last forever in flutter

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, flutter, apk

I was facing a lot of errors after I enabled multidex in my android flutter application and I fixed the error by enabling ndk filters in my app build gradle. Now the apk is not crashing but is taking forever to install so I close the aok installation then reopen it and I am prompted with update your app since I opened 2 installations at the same time. I proceed With the update and it finishes in 5 seconds. Is there anything I should do on the java side for the multidex? or is their anything I should edit so that the install works properly?
this is my ndk filter

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips", "arm64-v8a"
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21009 - is this related to your issue?

Comment: will read and see

Comment: You should remove `armeabi` and `mips` at the very least. They have been deprecated and are no longer supported by recent versions of the NDK.

Comment: Ok will try and see

Comment: l I removed them from the ndk, the app now installs faster but still slower than usual.About 3min.